# AWS SQS concurrent processing issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS configured to get message for each file file upload in a S3 bucket. And SQS messages will be processed  using camel framework. Everything works fine in this process until some 50K concurrent files were uploaded. So SQS received 50K messages and those message are not processed.
only some 10K messages are processed. After increasing visibility timeout to 10 mins this problem is resolved. But can any one tell me how to fix the root cause.

S3 -> SQS - > CAMEL process

issue when concurrent 50K files pushed and camel process take about 7 to 8 mins to process those SQS messages. If camel takes more then 10 mins this problem is reappearing

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your current visibility timeout?

Comment: Previously it was 3 min and changed it to 5 min

Comment: Well if your tasks take 8 minutes, then 5 minitue is not enough.

Comment: So only way to solve this issue is by increasing visibility time?